# Jar file will not execute

Tags: java, jar

it's been several years since I've programmed anything, but I wrote this little program to help with an issue we're having at work.  i did some homework on how to make a jar file and followed those steps.  When I try to execute the created jar file, nothing happens.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Source Code**:

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CardOutput
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {   

        String inputA;
        JFrame parent = new JFrame();

        boolean truth = true;

        while(truth)
        {
            inputA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Swipe Card");

            if(inputA.length() == 0)
            {
                truth = false;
            }
            else if(inputA.length() != 14)
            {
                inputA = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid Card Number \n" + "Please Swipe Card");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "Your Card Number is " + inputA.substring(4,13));
            }
        }       
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "Program is now ending");  
    System.exit(0);
    }   
}
```

**Manifest file line:** Main-Class: CardOutput.class

**Batch file I created to form the .jar file:**

```
@ECHO OFF
C:
CD "C:\Users\timmcj\Desktop\CardOutput
"C:\Program Files\Java\JDK1.7.0_09\bin\jar.exe" cvfm CardOutput.jar manifest.txt *.class
PAUSE
```

Comment: Canonical "loop forever" is `while (true) {...}`. IMO using a variable for that obfuscates things, particularly when `truth == false`.

Answer (score 2):

Take the .class out of your mainifest. just use the class name and it should run.

java -jar yourjar.jar

Comment: Not a problem. I'm glad I could help.